# Why cant't Arduino deal with high precision numbers?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

In my project I need to make some calculations with high-precision numbers. But I noticed that the answers are not correct. The code bellow shows what I mean.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  double l = 32.48750458;
  double n = 32.48751068;
  double im = l - n;
  double im1 = im * 0.605;
  double cs = 32.48751068 + im;
  Serial.println(l, 8);
  Serial.println(n, 8);
  Serial.println(im1, 8);
  Serial.println(cs, 8); 
}

void loop() {
}
```

The output of this code on the serial monitor is:

```
32.48750305
32.48751068
-0.00000462
32.48750305
```

So how can I deal with this precision in Arduino?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783982/operation-at-two-high-precision-number-within-matrix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [operation at two high precision number within matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783982/operation-at-two-high-precision-number-within-matrix)

Comment: Also asked at: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=552543 If you're going to do that then please be considerate enough to add links to the other places you cross posted. This will let us avoid wasting time due to duplicate effort and also help others who have the same questions and find your post to discover all the relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most Arduino the double data type doesn't exist.  They all end up really being just regular float.  The arduino just doesn't have the muscle to be playing with double precision numbers.  The code generated wouldn't leave room for the rest of your program.

Floating point numbers just aren't that precise.  They get about 6 or 7 digits of precision.  Quite often it is better to use unsigned long and stick with fixed point math so you can get at least 9 digits and there aren't any approximations.

Comment: Fro that link:  "That is, the double implementation is exactly the same as the float, with no gain in precision."

Comment: Yes, just like you were saying. That's why I added the 'official' link.

Comment: TBH a "real" `double` implementation for AVR could probably fit, but IMO if you ask for it it's a sign that you are doing something wrong. AVRs are 8 bit microcontrollers, you should be thankful that they manage to do arithmetic on 16 and 32 bit integers , definitely not the place for floating point calculations. Pretty much anything you generally need to do on a micro can be done in fixed precision with a huge speedup (and, if the base Arduino library didn't use FP, significant reduction in code size).

Comment: @Delta_G ,, I don't really understand what you meant by **better to use unsigned long and stick with fixed point math** , but I tried to use unsigned long instead of double and it does not work. also I tried arduino duo instead of uno but I have the same problem.

Comment: Fixed point math means that if you want volts to 3 decimal places you use millivolts instead so it all comes out as integers.  Fix your units so you don't need decimals.  Put the decimals back in when you display to the humans.

Comment: I overlap with @Delta_G a little ...  The idea behind fixed-point numbers is to scale all your floating point values by some fixed amount, and then treat all your values as integers. So, if we scale by 100, then 12.34 becomes 1234. The AVR compiler supports int64_t, so we can get about 18 digits with that.  There's also <stdfix.h> which defines standard fixed-point data types. For me, this is part of the fun of programming on "small-iron" - getting big jobs done with little resources.  Alternatively, see Nick Gammon's BigNum library: https://github.com/nickgammon/BigNumber

Comment: > `In my project I need to make some calculations with high-precision numbers`
Here's your problem. In the real world, you make a big mistake if you measure two things and get 32.48750458 and 32.48751068 as the results of your measurements and think you can say anything about their difference.